# How Jsp will recognize will bundle to refer of same name but different version in cq5 or osgi?

Tags: osgi, aem, osgi-bundle

As it is mentioned we can install multiple bundles of different versions in OSGI. SO if I have two versions of my Bundle and both are active . How will my jsp recognize which bundle has to refer ?

Answer (score 0):

In short, you can't do this from a JSP. In AEM/Sling, all JSPs (in fact, all resource scripts) share a single classloader and there's no way to specify a package import version. As a result, if you have two bundles exporting the same package with different versions (which is generally what would happen in the scenario you described), you can't know which version will be used in your JSPs. I believe currently it is whatever is exported by the bundle with the lowest ID, but this is not at all guaranteed and shouldn't be depended upon.

You should try to avoid this scenario by reducing your JSPs hard dependency on Java implementation classes and instead use OSGi services for whatever it is you are trying to accomplish. With services, it is relatively easy to select a particular service implementation by the use of a filter.

For example, if multiple bundles have services registered with the `com.myco.Foo` interface (and this interface is exported by a common bundle) and each service registration has some unique property set (in my example below, this property is named `type`, but that's arbitrary), you can do something like this:

```
<% 
   Foo[] foos = sling.getService(Foo.class, "(type=something)"); 
   if (foos != null && foos.length == 1) {
       Foo foo = foos[0];
       // do something with foo
   }
 %>
```

Answer (score 0):

For every Import-Package package declaration, there must be a corresponding Export-Package with the same package
Bundles can also attach other attributes to the packages it imports or exports.

For ex:-
Bundle-Name: Bundle A
Import-Package: org.apache.foo;version="1.2.0"

This means, Bundle-A has a dependency on package org.apache.foo with a minimum version of 1.2.0.
Although with OSGI you can specify a range of versions, if you don't specify a range but rather use a fixed version, it will result in a meaning of "a minimum" of the fixed value.
If there is a higher version for that same package, the higher version will be used. 
So Bundle-A will not resolve correctly unless there is a corresponding bundle B that exports the required package

Bundle-Name: Bundle B
Export-Package: org.apache.foo;version="1.2.0"

Note that the reverse is not true.If Bundle B exported version 1.2.0, Bundle A is not required to specify a version 1.2.0.
This is because imports declare the versions they need. An exported version does not specify anything.

You can check the existing versions of your bundles in the depfinder-"http://localhost:****/system/console/depfinder"

In simple we can say JSP will recognise the bundles through version only.
If there are two versions with similar name,it will recognise the latest version.
Bundles installed first are used to satisfy a dependency when multiple packages with the same version are found.